# How can you launch an installed s40 application via a link within a web page?

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40

We have our own application installed in the s40 device.  Can we call it via a url or command from within a web page or web app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Its called OTA.
Start your emulator, go to the Browser, type the link. The installation process starts automatically.

Keep in mind that the link should point to a jad or the jar file located in the server.